# ADOMD data reader is slow when loading

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, ssas, adomd.net

Really hoping somebody can help me.

In our application I have an MDX query with the following characteristics:

- 5 dimensions and 2 measures
- Returns 160k rows
- Written in MDX
- **Execution time is 34 seconds.**

Despite taking a while and returning a massive amount of rows, this is quite acceptable and the client assures me they are going to use all the data.

The problem comes when I'm trying to access the data inside my application.

- Connecting to the OLAP database by using an ADOMDConnection works perfectly
- Creating a data reader by using an ADOMDDatareader works perfectly
- **Loading the data via datareader takes more than 5 minutes**

Even if I don't transfer the data into a dataset/datatable and simply increase a counter via the "dataReader.Read()" command (via a while loop) it takes over 5 minutes. I've tried retrieving the data via an ADOMDDataAdapter (6 minutes) and a Cellset (6 minutes +).

My application has the following properties:

- Console application (for testing purposes)
- Using VB.Net, will also test in C#
- Visual Studio 2015
- SQL Server 2014
- Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient v9.0.5

Can anybody perhaps assist me in speeding this up or just point me in a direction I can look? Would using a newer version of the AdomdClient help? Another technology I can use altogether? Is there something in the cube that I can improve?

Thanks!

Comment: `Loading the data via datareader takes more than 5 minutes`, showing some code will help for sure. `Even if I don't transfer the data into a dataset/datatable and simply increase a counter via the "dataReader.Read()" command (via a while loop) it takes over 5 minutes` are you saying just loading a `dataset` and or `datatable` takes 5 minutes? Please post your current code so we can further help you. Also with that many records IMO you should be using the adapter and then fill a `datatable` then access that data easily instead of using the `datareader`...

Comment: Thank you, it seems a network issue was causing the problem, but the adapter is also proving faster than my current method. Will definitely look further into that!

Comment: You are welcome, good luck!